# How to split List in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections, partitioning

How to split a list `L` (or any other collection) into 2 lists, so that the first one contains 80% of `L` and the second one contains the rest?

Comment: The API suggests that there's a method called `splitAt`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val (first80pct, rest) = L.splitAt(L.size * 4 / 5)
```

You would want to be careful of using this on a collection without a definite length (eg. streams).

Comment: Also be careful about edge cases - e.g. the above puts the only element into "rest" if L is size 1. If we want *at least* 80% in the first one, then `math.ceil(L.size * 0.80).toInt` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Could that be rewritten as `(L.size * 0.8).ceil.toInt`?